# GridLayout - Aligning Element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I am trying to reduce the space between 2 columns, have tried using negative margins, but did not work. Is there a way to bring the 2 elements in the image closer ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:columnCount="8">
  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/settings" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentCityName"
        android:layout_column="2"     
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="City name"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        />
  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="7"

        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/reload" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/currentWeatherImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnSpan="8"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/cloud" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/humidityIcon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"         
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/humidity" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/humidity"       
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/temperature"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:textSize="49sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/windSpeedIcon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/wind" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/windSpeed"
        android:textSize="12sp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <!-- android:layout_width="40dp" -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/precipitationIcon"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/precipitation"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/windDirection16Point"          
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/weatherDescription"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:layout_columnSpan="8"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" 
    android:layout_columnSpan="8" />    
<EditText
    android:minLines="4"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_columnSpan="8"/>
```

[image: output image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest implementing the entire view using a RelativeLayout, should be the best solution for the entire view.

Comment: This seems trivial to do in a `RelativeLayout` I would use that.

Answer (score 2):

You are tackling the wrong problem – you are asking how to reduce the space between columns in a grid layout, but maybe you should’t have used such a layout in the first place!

What you should have been using for your specific layout, is a combination of **[relative positioning](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and *compound drawables*** (here, with `android:drawableStart`).

[image: Result of using the below-mentioned code]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#d89018"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/temperature"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="25 ℃"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="49sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/humidity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/humidity"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="83 %"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/windSpeed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/wind"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="19 km/h"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/precipitation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/precipitation"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="0.1 mm"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/windDirection16Point"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/windSpeed"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/windDirection"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="NNW"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Not only this layout is simpler, you also let Android take care of all the spacing for you. **To change the spacing between the compound drawable and the text, use `android:drawablePadding`** in the layout’s code above; in Java code, that would be [`TextView.setCompoundDrawablePadding`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablePadding(int))).

---

> Icons used for the sample: [water](https://icons8.com/web-app/7646/water), [windsock](https://icons8.com/web-app/16977/windsock), [rainy-weather](https://icons8.com/web-app/33690/rainy-weather) and [wind-rose](https://icons8.com/web-app/5666/wind-rose).

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is that your Views are being stretched because they are trying to match the width of another view in their columns.

Try decreasing the columnSpan of your Views or separate your layout into two separate GridLayouts.

Or, consider using a different layout altogether. I would recommend RelativeLayout here instead of GridLayout, but I don't know how this fits into a larger window.

Comment: When i place elements inside LinearLayout (nested inside gridlayout), the element is not displayed at all http://pastebin.com/4wXpmV9d

Answer (score 0):

try this:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="100dp">

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/col1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_weight="2.4"
      >
        <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/col1_row1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          >   
          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="83%"/>
      </LinearLayout>         
        <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/col1_row2"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          >   
          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="1.0mm"/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>  

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/col2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_weight="2.0"
      android:gravity="center"
      >
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="25'"
          android:textSize="50dp"
          />      
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/col3"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_weight="2.4"
      >
        <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/col3_row1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          >   
          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="19Km"/>
      </LinearLayout>         
        <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/col3_row2"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          >   
          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="NNW"/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Deep layouts - Layouts with too much nesting are bad for performance. Consider using flatter layouts such as RelativeLayout or GridLayout to improve performance. The default maximum depth is 10.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Comment: i don't think the depth 3 is too much!

Comment: You are invited to argue with the example in the article I linked.

Comment: you'r right, if the requested layout was final! i guess it's gonna probably grow and contains more items. so a simple gridlayout is not enough.

Comment: If he'll add more items that just a better reason to make a more efficient one, and would probably be easier to add items using a RelativeLayout.

Comment: if more items can be simply arranged! but a nested design obviously need a multi-layer layout. but in the case of current question, i give the right to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change usedefaultMargins to false and give your own margins to the elements.

```
android:useDefaultMargins="false";
```